# cl.exe -c /DEFAULTLIB:"MYLIB"? How to add default libs to .obj files from command line?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

When I create `.obj` files with `cl.exe`, they have:

```
/DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES"
```

Inside them. How to add more libs? cl.exe has no `/DEFAULTLIB` argument.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx

Comment: So, from command line it's /FI "file-with-pragmas"